# Which path of liberation does the name "bhavana gamya" belongs to?

Tags: moksha, meaning, lalita-sahasranama

There are four names in [Lalitha Sahastranaamas](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Sahasranamam) that ends with the word **gamya**. They are

> 113 : **Bhavana gamya** --- She who can be attained by thinking
>
> 119 : **Bhakthi gamya** --- She who can be reached by devotion
>
> 641 : **Dhyana gamya**    --- She who can be attained by meditation
>
> 980 : **Gnana gamya**     --- She who can be attained by knowledge

I am assuming that each name represents a path of liberation. I think the mapping is as follows

> **Bhakthi gamya** --- Bhakthi marga
>
> **Gnana gamya**   --- Ganana marga

I have doubt regarding the remaining two names, i think the following may be correct

> **Dhyana gamya**  --- Yoga marga.

Is it correct?

I am not sure about the remaining one i.e., **Bhavana gamya**. Which path of liberation does it correspond to?

Comment: "Bhava" is not just thinking. It's more like intent or emotion that he must have while worshiping. But without worshiping he cannot have "Bhava". Its not a path towards liberation, but a element neccessary for.