# What is "kalagamya" in saraswati sahastranaamas?

Tags: meaning, lalita-sahasranama, saraswati-sahasranama

There are four names in Lalitha Sahastranaama stotram [that ends with gamya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48645/which-path-of-liberation-does-the-name-bhavana-gamya-belongs-to). They are **Bhavana gamya, Bhakthi gamya, Dhyana gamya, and Gnana gamya.**

There are similar names in Saraswati sahastranaamas also. I compiled from the [two Saraswati sahastranaamas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/are-there-any-saraswati-sahastranaamas-other-than-those-from-skanda-purana-and-r).

> **From Skanda purana**
>
> Gamya
>
> mantragamya
>
> **From Rudra Yamala Tantram**
>
> viragamya
>
> yogagamya (2)
>
> kalagamya

The name yoga-gamya is repeated twice. There may be differences in semantics. But I have difficulty in understanding the meaning of the name **kalagamya**.

What is **kala** here? Is it the name of a sadhana? What exactly it is and how it helps a sadhaka to reach ma, Saraswati?

Comment: bhakti-gamyaa, means -accessible/attainable by the culmination of bhakti , (in other words)the destination of bhakti. In similar lines ,(there are chatushasti kalas(64 art forms)).I guess it could be.., by the culmination of devotion thru an art form(kala), Ma Saraswati is attainable(gamyaa). so She is Kalagamyaa.